# `eval` in chrome extension in mv3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, eval

I'm looking for a way to use `eval` within a popup chrome extension using mv3.

Looking this up, I found this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/sandboxingEval/). Of course, I wanted more info on `sandbox`, which led me [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/sandbox/), and it states:

> Warning: Starting in version 57, Chrome will no longer allow external web content (including embedded frames and scripts) inside sandboxed pages. Please use a webview instead.

So I visited the [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webviewTag/) page and it says:

> This API is part of the deprecated Chrome Apps platform. Learn more about migrating your app.

I am now a bit unsure of what to do, specially since the webview page was last updated on 2018.

Does anyone know how I should go about using `eval` in a MV3 popup chrome extension?

Comment: The documentation server is broken. You can use sandboxed pages in MV3.

Comment: @wOxxOm, may use external script in a sandboxed page now?

Comment: No, https://crbug.com/1220994.

Comment: @wOxxOm, it's sad, but thank you for the clarification.